# Swift closure giving function to variable

Tags: swift, closures

```
class ClassA {

    var callback : (()->())?

    func someAction() {
        callback?()
    }
}

class ClassB {

    func caller() {
        let a = ClassA()
        a.callback = {
            print("hello")
            //d do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I want to move the ClassB callback implementation to seperate function. as below

```
a.callback = somefunc()
```

But this is **not possible** as we are giving ***function to variable***

And I dont want

```
a.callback = { somefunc() }
```

Is there a way to call a funtion if at all?

Comment: Just remove the parenthesis. a.callback = somefunc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `()` to `someFunc` means that you are calling the function and this will evaluate to the return value of `someFunc`, which is `Void`.

You need to refer to the function directly, without calling it. Just remove the `()`:

```
a.callback = someFunc
```

Comment: How to call if the closure has parameters like (String, Int) -> Void

Comment: got it someFunc(st:id:)